# Question about FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I was reading through the [documentation of Factory Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) and came across this code block.

```
#The behavior of the association method varies depending on the build strategy used for the parent object.

#Builds and saves a User and a Post
post = FactoryGirl.create(:post)
post.new_record?       # => false
post.author.new_record # => false

# Builds and saves a User, and then builds but does not save a Post
post = FactoryGirl.build(:post)
post.new_record?       # => true
post.author.new_record # => false
```

I'm new to Factory Girl, but shouldn't the first code example return true for new_record? I'm confused why it returns false if the post is built and saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**new_record?()** public
Returns true if this object hasn’t been saved yet — that is, a record for the object doesn’t exist yet; otherwise, returns false.
This method is deprecated on the latest stable version of Rails.

**Edit:**
Oops, looks like the link was broken. Fixed.
[new_record?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/new_record%3F)

Comment: Ahh. I see. It's a pretty confusing term, so I'm glad it's deprecated. I guess they haven't gotten around to update the docs yet. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html